# How do I prove that there is no other :$k=9,12,18$ for which this fails :$\sigma^k(114) \equiv 0\mod 6 $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, congruences, divisor-sum, research

let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of divisors for a positive integer for example :

$$\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=12$$ .

I have performed some calculations in wolfram alpha about the  sum divisors of this number:

$q=114$ such that I got this :$\sigma(114)=240\equiv 0\mod 6 $ and $\sigma(\sigma(114))=744\equiv 0\mod 6 $ and $\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(114)))=1920\equiv 0\mod 6 ,\cdots$ .

My question here is :How do I  prove that there is no other :$k=9,12,18$ for which this fails :$$\sigma^k(114) \equiv 0\mod 6 $$ then what is the place of this number in number thoery  ?

Note (01):* I think that is the only integer fails only for $k=9,12,18$

Note (02) :$\sigma^k(114)=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(114\cdots))))))),k-th $

Thank you for any help .

Comment: Just to clarify:  are you saying that if $a_1$ = 114 and $a_n$ = $\sigma(a_{n-1})$ for n >1, then each of the $a_k$ is divisible by 6?  why do you distinguish the cases k = 9,12,18?

Comment: in those cases : 9,12,18  is not true , pleas look the example

Comment: Pleas look this :$\sigma(114)=240\equiv 0\mod 6 $ and $\sigma(\sigma(114))=744\equiv 0\mod 6 $ and $\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(114)))=1920\equiv 0\mod 6 ,\cdots$, and in the case of k=9,12,18 , the equation is false

Comment: and i think this number :114 has a good place in number theory if what i claimed stay true

Comment: Interesting speculation over the integer 114.To me it seems very difficult to prove what you ask because, in appearance, we have no a way  to know $\sigma^k(114)$ for arbitrary $k$. 
 And I do not believe this represent an exclusive property of 114  in case it be true (I mean,it could be true for other integers X with corresponding other numbers than $9, 12, 18, 6$). But I give here just a feeling and this have no real validity.

Comment: @Ataulfo,could u give me an example of this integer X ?

Comment: @Ataulfo ,if it were true it will be exclusive property of 114 as 114 =0mod(6) , i meant this number has a great relationship with the integer 6

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik: I wish you're right. Find another number could be difficult if there was a certain X (the big problem I see is the calculation of $\sigma^k(X)$)

Comment: do you meant there is no algorithm to calculate it ?

Comment: I don't know.  Noting that $114=6\cdot19$ and because of $19$ and $17$ are twin, I entertained myself (but not enough!) with $102=6\cdot17$. I verify that $\sigma^k(102)\equiv 0$ (mod $6$) for $k=1,2,3,4,8$ but it fails for $k=5, 6,7$. Good luck if you persist in this.

Comment: but 114 fails only for :9,12,18 for k\leq 720 , for the calculation of sum of divisors there are many algorithm just to check this calculator :http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/divisorscalculator.htm

Comment: @Ataulfo, 102 divisors sum modulo 6 fails for many cases

Answer (score 0):

Hint for fast calculation of sigma in a chain...

Let a number be written as
$$
\prod p^{n_p},
$$
where $p$ are prime numbers. Then we have
$$
\sigma\Big(\prod p^{n_p}\Big) = \prod \frac{p^{n_p+1}-1}{p-1}.
$$

Example:
$$
\sigma(114) = \sigma(2 \times 3 \times 19)
= \frac{2^2-1}{2-1} \frac{3^2-1}{3-1} \frac{19^2-1}{19-1}
= 3 \times 4 \times 20
= 2^4 \times 3 \times 5
$$
$$
\sigma^2(114) = \sigma(2^4 \times 3 \times 5)
= 31 \times 4 \times 6
= 2^3 \times 3 \times 31
$$
$$
\sigma^3(114) = \sigma(2^3 \times 3 \times 31)
= 15 \times 4 \times 32
= 2^7 \times 3 \times 5
$$
$$
\sigma^4(114) = 2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 17\\
\sigma^5(114) = 2^2 \times 3^4 \times 5 \times 13\\
\sigma^6(114) = 2^2 \times 3 \times 7^2 \times 11\\
\sigma^7(114) = 2^2 \times 3 \times 7^2 \times 19^2\\
\sigma^8(114) = 2^2 \times 3^2 \times 7 \times 19 \times 127\\
\sigma^9(114) = 2^{13} \times 5 \times 7 \times 13\\
$$

and $\sigma^9(114)$ is not dividable by $3$...

So-far, I see no pattern...

You could write a computer program to run the sequence and check it...

Comment: valks , thank you for your answer but this is not a proof and just you are confirmed wether k=9 or will 12,18 is not works and fail , the main question is how do u confirme it's only fails with k=9,12,18 ? "zeraoulia rafik"

Comment: @zeraouliarafik, I agree - I only posted it as a hint for fast calculating the recursion. Yet, I do not see any pattern...

Comment: valks :you can take a look at this question:http://mathoverflow.net/q/211567/74330 may you can find as an idea for proof

Comment: The generalized question is $\sigma^k(x) \equiv 0 \mod y$...